# React SetState within a async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I'm trying to  make a weather application and I am stuck using the async/await function.

I have a function which does a axios call to an api and then I'm trying to set some state variables. The think is that it seems the application is running the setState methods before the promise is resolved.

Here is the method that makes the axios call.

```
const fetchWeeklyWeather = async () => {

    try {
        let response = await axios.get(url);

        console.log('%cFetch Weekly Weather Response:', 'color: #bada55', response);

        setCurrentWeather(response.data.current);
        setWeeklyWeather(response.data.daily);
        setWeatherAlerts(response.data.alerts);
    } catch (err) {
        // Handle Error Here
        console.error(err);
    }
}
```

And I call that method on the componentDidMount like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchWeeklyWeather();

    console.log("Current Weather", currentWeather);
    console.log("Weekly Weather", weeklyWeather);
    console.log("Weather alerts", weatherAlerts);

    formatData(weeklyWeather);
}, []);
```

It is weird because sometimes it works but most of the time it does not. I guess I'm not doing the right think with the async/await. Can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: Yes, you don't  use async-await correctly. fetchWeeklyWeather returns a promise, and you don't wait for it. Another problem is what the answer says, state updates can be asynchronous too. You should either access weeklyWeather in another effect, or just return data you need from fetchWeeklyWeather and don't rely on the state here

Comment: *"you don't use async-await correctly"* OPs use of async/await is perfectly fine. *"fetchWeeklyWeather returns a promise, and you don't wait for it"* pointless. The effect-function can not be async, and even `then()` is not an option because the state would still not have been updated when that runs. *"state updates can be asynchronous too"* They are, *always*! That's why awaiting of `fetchWeeklyWeather()` is no option. In FunctionComponents there is no notification that tells you when the state has been updated. The Component re-renders, why? Only React knows.

Comment: Thanks guys for you answers. I'll try to fix it this evening and see if i get something.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> useEffect(() => {
>     fetchWeeklyWeather();
>
>     console.log("Current Weather", currentWeather);
>     console.log("Weekly Weather", weeklyWeather);
>     console.log("Weather alerts", weatherAlerts);
>
>     formatData(weeklyWeather);
> }, []);
> ```

The callback is only executed on component mount (empty dependancy array), so the `console.log()` statements will only log the initial values of `currentWeather`, `weeklyWeather` and `weatherAlerts`, not the values that are set retrieved by `axios`.

To fix this you should separate the `useEffect` callback into multiple callbacks.

```
// runs on component mount
useEffect(() => {
  fetchWeeklyWeather();
}, []);

// runs on component mount and whenever currentWeather changes
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Current Weather", currentWeather);
}, [currentWeather]);

// runs on component mount and whenever weeklyWeather changes
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Weekly Weather", weeklyWeather);
  formatData(weeklyWeather);
}, [weeklyWeather]);

// runs on component mount and whenever weatherAlerts changes
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Weather alerts", weatherAlerts);
}, [weatherAlerts]);
```

The above should log `currentWeather` twice. Once with the initial value, and once with the value that is loaded by `axios`. The same applies for `weeklyWeather` and `weatherAlerts`.

Note that `formatData()` is also called twice. So it must be able to handle the  call with the initial data. If this initial data is `null` you might want to skip the initial call.

```
const [weeklyWeather, setWeeklyWeather] = useState(null);
//                     initial weeklyWeather value ^^^^

// ...

// runs on component mount and whenever weeklyWeather changes
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Weekly Weather", weeklyWeather);

  // skip the formatData() call if weeklyWeather is null
  if (weeklyWeather) formatData(weeklyWeather);
}, [weeklyWeather]);
```

The above will skip the `formatData()` call when `weeklyWeather` is `null` (or any other falsy value). Meaning that it will not be called for the initial value, but it is called once the `axios` response updated the state.

Answer (score 0):

because your function named 'fetchWeeklyWeather' is an async function, you call the 'fetchWeeklyWeather' in your 'useEffect' hook as a sync function, so you can't log right result below.

you should call like this:

```js
useEffect(()=>{
  fetchWeeklyWeather()
  .then(()=>{
  // do the console.log
  })
  .catch(err=>console.error(err))
},[]);
```

Answer (score -1):

solved this

```
this.setState((prevState) => {return {page: prevState.page + 1});
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**